# Keras Sequential model fit shape

Tags: python, keras

I could find similar questions in other threads but i could not solve my issue so I hope to have an answer here.
I am trying to train a model with the following code:

```
''' split the sample '''
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(csvFile['Tweet'], csvFile['sent_score'], test_size= 0.20, shuffle=False)
'''add layers to define the input dimension of our feature vectors'''
input_dim = len(X_train)  # Number of features

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

''' specifies the optimizer and the loss function '''
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
X_test = np.asarray(X_test)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)

''' fit the model '''
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)
```

I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 209, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (23136,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

And when I try to reshape as requested by the error (23136,). I got the opposite error as follow. Probably the key here is the error is not on the same layer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_2_input to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (23136,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input_dim = len(X_train)` is not the number of features but the number of samples... change it to `input_dim = X_train.shape[-1]`

here a dummy example:

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, 23136)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 23136)

input_dim = 1 # or X.shape[-1] if more feature are present

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: right, it was the sample length... The number of dimension is 1

Comment: you have to pass to input_dim the number of features... so X_train.shape[-1] or 1 are ok

Comment: I also added a dummy example

Comment: @delalma let me know if there are problems

Comment: Thanks, it seem that the previous error is gone but I now have the following on the same row: `could not convert string to float: "RT @bethereumteam: We're launching something huge for our #Telegram community next-week! #Sportsbetting directly in our group with a lotter‚Ä¶"` I don't understand why Keras needs to change to float. This is one of the sample in X_test...

Comment: This is clear... your passing text to your model and you can't. you have to convert it to number. This is not related to your original question. I suggest you mark this as anwer and made a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape    

model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((X_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=(X_train.shape[1],1), activation='relu'))
```

Comment: is this a numpy reshape ? I had an error: model.add(np.reshape((X_train.shape[1],1)))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Nope it's a keras reshape, I've added it to the answer.